# Query Plan of postgres with indexes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres table having the following schema

```
     Table "public.myTable"
  Column               |           Type           | Modifiers 
-----------             +--------------------------+-----------
 serial_number         | character varying(255)   | 
 name                  | character varying(255)   | 
 Designation           | character varying(255)   | 
 place                 | character varying(255)   | 
 timeOfJoining         | timestamp with time zone | 
 timeOfLeaving               | timestamp with time zone | 

Indexes:
    "name_Designation_place" btree (name, Designation, place)
    "Designation_place_name" btree (Designation, place, name)
    "Designation_name_place" btree (Designation, name, place)
    "timeOfJoining_timeOfLeaving" btree (timeOfJoining, timeOfLeaving)
    "timeOfJoining_timeOfLeaving" btree (timeOfJoining, timeOfLeaving)
```

Now when I run the query of the form:

```
explain analyze select place from myTable where Designation='Manager' and timeOfJoining>'1930-10-10';
```

I am getting the following plan:

```
Index Scan using Designation_place_name on myTable  (cost=0.00..67701.36 rows=22043 width=27) (actual time=0.061..3.796 rows=3376 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((relation)::text = 'Manager'::text)
   Filter: (timeOfJoining > '1930-10-10 00:00:00+05:53:20'::timestamp with time zone)
 Total runtime: 4.082 ms
(4 rows)
```

Now I am unable to understand as to how the query plan is executed. Does the query plan first retrieve the serial_number from the index Designation_place_name on myTable and then goes to myTable and fetches the rows and then performs the filtering on timeOfJoining

OR

Does the query plan fetch both the indexes timeOfJoining_timeOfLeaving and Designation_place_name and then performs a join, and upon this join the filtering is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plan:

```
Index Scan using Designation_place_name on myTable  (cost=0.00..67701.36 rows=22043 width=27) (actual time=0.061..3.796 rows=3376 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((relation)::text = 'Manager'::text)
   Filter: (timeOfJoining > '1930-10-10 00:00:00+05:53:20'::timestamp with time zone)
 Total runtime: 4.082 ms
(4 rows)
```

Basically means:

1. Using the Designation_place_name index
2. Find rows that fit the index condition relation = 'Manager'
3. Keep only rows that match the timeOfJoining criteria

During step 2, disk pages are accessed "randomly", rather than sequentially, which is to say the index contains the address of matching rows on disk, and Postgres visits these addresses in the order indicated by the index. (This can be costly, btw. Sometimes, the planner will decide its cheaper to just read the entire table (seq scan) or batch fetch all rows on a page while ignoring the order indicated by the index (bitmap index scan).)

Note: there are no (table) joins in that query. Had there been one, you'd have seen extra indentation levels. Read them from most indented to least indented.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..does postgres maintain the indexes in-memory or are they maintained in disk

Comment: Someone withh more understanding of Postgres' internals will hopefully chime in on that. To the best of my knowledge, indexes get cached. The more frequently you use them, the more likely they'll be in memory -- assuming they're small enough to fit in memory, of course.

Comment: Thanks again for replying. I need to learn Postgres internals like these..any idea from where I can know about them

Comment: IMO step#3 (the filter step) involves visiting the actual data table, since `timeOfJoining` is not present in the `Designation_place_name` index. This may cause the same data page to be fetched multiple times, but the second (and later) hits will _probably_ be handled by the buffercache and OS-cache.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the query plan fetch both the indexes timeOfJoining_timeOfLeaving and Designation_place_name and then performs a join, and upon this join the filtering is done?

Since the index `timeOfJoining_timeOfLeaving` is not mentioned in the plan, it is not used. It's that simple.

> Does the query plan first retrieve the serial_number from the index Designation_place_name on myTable and then goes to myTable and fetches the rows and then performs the filtering on timeOfJoining?

Mostly: Yes. But not the `serial_number` is used but an internal type of link. Besides of that minor point this is what the plan tells you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..does postgres maintain the indexes in-memory or are they maintained in disk

Comment: PostgreSQL - as any other large database - stores indizes on disc and load the required parts into memory. The general thinking in PostgreSQL land is, that the OS buffer cache is used for stuff which is often needed. This includes the indizes. So - if you have a small index ("small" in relation to your RAM size) which is used often, then it is likely cached in the buffer cache.