# Query plan for database table containing trillions of records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have a big table containing trillions of records of the following schema (Here serial no. is the key):

```
                  MyTable
 Column               |           Type           | Modifiers 
-----------             +--------------------------+-----------
 serial_number         | int    | 
 name                  | character varying(255)   | 
 Designation           | character varying(255)   | 
 place                 | character varying(255)   | 
 timeOfJoining         | timestamp with time zone | 
 timeOfLeaving         | timestamp with time zone |
```

Now I want to fire queries of the form given below on this table:

```
select place from myTable where Designation='Manager' and timeOfJoining>'1930-10-10' and timeOfLeaving<'1950-10-10';
```

My aim is to achieve fast query execution times. Since, I am designing my own database from scratch, therefore I have the following options. Please guide me as to which one of the two options will be faster.

1. Create 2 separate table. Here, table1 contains the schema (serial_no, name, Designation, place) and table 2 contains the schema (serial_no, timeOfJoining, timeOfLeaving). And then perform a merge join between the two tables. Here, serial_no is the key in both the tables
2. Keep one single table MyTable. And run the following plan: Create an index Designation_place_name and using the Designation_place_name index, find rows that fit the index condition relation = 'Manager'(The rows on disc are accessed randomly) and then using the filter function keep only rows that match the timeOfJoining criteria.

Please help me figure out which one will be faster. It'll be great if you could also tell me the respective pros and cons.

EDIT: I intend to use my table as read-only.

Comment: Don't miss the tsrange type, if you've still the option of changing the schema like that: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rangetypes.html -- they allow to be indexed efficiently using e.g. GIST indexes.

Comment: By the information you gave I see no reason for splitting the tables. Unless splitting them allows you to reduce the total amount of data (i.e. remove duplication) that is. As for what is the best solution for your problem, that also depends on how you use it (read-only? lots of updates? lots of inserts?)

Comment: Assuming you will only be querying 1 designation at a time, you could consider partitioning based on that.

Comment: In your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17260571/905902 , I hesitated to comment on your data model. Having 4 varchar fields, each with a presumably low number of distinct values (cardinality) does not look too good. A varchar as a primary key does not feel too good, either. Also: you don't show any PK/FK constraints, maybe you don't have them ? (except for the PK , probably)

Comment: @RoseBeck . . . Trillions of records is a *lot* of records.  There are about 7 billion people on earth, so that is about 300 records per person.  Or, over the course of ten years, over 3,000 records per second.  What will you be doing with the data?  That has a lot of influence on how you store it.

Comment: @WoLpH I may query on multiple designations at a time. Also I intend to use the database in a read-only manner.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to find out names, designation, place etc given temporal constraints like timeOfJoining>someValue and timeOfLeaving<someValue

Comment: @RoseBeck: I beg to ask... What kind of datasource gives you the location of managers joining and leaving a place at a given point in time? The NSA's PRISM or something? :-)

Comment: serial_number is character varying(255)?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Sorry serial_no are integers. Thanks for pointing this. But does that make any difference

Comment: Both options #1 and #2 are ludicrously inadequate for trillions of rows on today's hardware. You want to look at distributed databases like `HadoopDB`

Comment: @DanielVérité Yes I know that they are inadequate. But my company can afford a lot of storage on hard-disk on its super-computers

Comment: Postgres has a table limit of 32TB currently. Compute your average row size, multiply that by 2 trillions, and I suspect it's already way over the limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are dealing with lots and lots of rows and you want to use a relational database, then your best bet for such a query is to satisfy it entirely in an index.  The example query is:

```
select place
from myTable
where Designation='Manager' and
      timeOfJoining > '1930-10-10' and
      timeOfLeaving < '1950-10-10';
```

The index should contain the four fields mentioned in the table.  This suggests an index like:  `mytable(Designation, timeOfJoining, timeOfLeaving, place)`.  Note that only the first two will be used for the `where` clause, because of the inequality.  However, most databases will do an index scan on the appropriate data.

With such a large amount of data, you have other problems. Although memory is getting cheaper and machines bigger, indexes often speed up queries because an index is smaller than the original table and faster to load in memory.  For "trillions" of records, you are talking about tens of trillions of bytes of memory, just for the index -- and I don't know which databases are able to manage that amount of memory.

Because this is such a large system, just the hardware costs are still going to be rather expensive.  I would suggest a custom solution that stored the data in a compressed format with special purpose indexing for the queries.  Off-the-shelf databases are great products applicable in almost all data problems.  However, this seems to be going near the limit of their applicability.

Even small efficiencies over an off-the-shelf database start to add up with such a large volume of data.  For instance, the layout of records on pages invariably leaves empty space on a page (records don't exactly fit on a page, the database has overhead that you may not need such as bits for nullability, and so on).  Say the overhead of the page structure and empty space amount to 5% of the size of a page.  For most applications, this is in the noise.  But 5% of 100 trillion bytes is 5 trillion bytes -- a lot of extra I/O time and wasted storage.

EDIT:

The real answer to the choice between the two options is to test them.  This shouldn't be hard, because you don't need to test them on trillions of rows -- and if you have the hardware for that, you have the hardware for smaller tests.  Take a few billions of rows on a machine with correspondingly less memory and CPUs and see which performs better.  Once you are satisfied with the results, multiply the data by 10 and try again.  You might want to do this one more time if you are not convinced of the results.

My opinion, though, is that the second is faster.  The first duplicates the "serial number" in both tables, adding 8 bytes to each row ("int" is typically 4-bytes and that isn't big enough, so you need bigint).  That alone will increase the I/O time and size of indexes for any analysis.  If you were considering a columnar data store (such as Vertica) then this space might be saved.  The savings on removing one or two columns is at the expense of reading in more bytes in total.

Also, don't store the raw form of any of the variables in the table.  The "Designation" should be in a lookup table as well as the "place" and "name", so each would be 4-bytes (that should be big enough for the dimensions, unless one is all people on earth).

But . . . The "best" solution in terms of cost, maintainability, and scalability is probably something like Hadoop.  That is how companies like Google and Yahoo manage vast quantities of data, and it seems apt here too.

Comment: @Gordon_Linoff thanks a lot for answering. But my company gives me the liberty to choose from either (1) or (2) of the options which I have written in the question. Considering the size of my dataset which one do you suggest.

Comment: @RoseBeck . . . Your organization has big problems if managers are dictating technical solutions at that level.  Of the two options you list, I would never advocate doing anything but an index lookup join on that volume of data, so that only leaves the second option.

Comment: dont you think the 2nd option will be less time efficient as after the index scan the rows in the relational table are accessed randomly. Whereas the first option stores the tables lexicographically and hence the random access are avoided. Can u please suggest as to why 2nd is more time efficient. Thanks for answering. I am really thankful to u for your effort. Hope you'll help me in clarifying this confusion too.

Comment: @RoseBeck . . . Can you explain what you mean for a parallel database to "store data lexicographically"?  I have no idea what that means.  I know what lexicographical order means.  I just don't know what it means in the context of parallel databases.  Rows in a table are inherently unordered.

Comment: Thanks for replying. What I mean by storing the table lexicographically is..I would store tables in option one in an index which would contain the entire record and this index would itself be ordered according to designation, place, name. Next time when I need to fetch a value..I would not fetch it from the table but rather I would look up in the index. Can u please now help me figure out which of the 2 options is the best for me

Answer (score 0):

Given the amount and type of data, I would suggest going with the second option. The upside is , you do not need to join anything. The join is usually very costly. However, in that case you are holding lots of redundant data.

The first option would be more memory efficient, the second more time efficient.

Furthermore, using indices, the DBMS is able to use index scans to read data from storage. Also, you should consider changing the variable length datatypes to fixed length datatypes, then the DBMS has an easier job of jumping between tuples as every tuple has a fixed (and known) length. In that case, operations like `skip the next 100000 tuples` are easy for the DBMS.

Comment: dont you think the 2nd option will be less time efficientas after the index scan the rows in the relational table are accessed randomly. Whereas the first option stores the tables lexicographically and hence the random access are avoided. Can u please justify as to why 2nd is more time efficient. Thanks for answering

Comment: I assume you are filling your database once. Hence, there are two time-consuming factors here: data access and join. Regardless the number of tables, random access will always occur. In my experience join cost are the big cost driver here. But tbh I can only guess, I never worked with such amounts of data.

Comment: Since in first option I am storing my tables lexicographically, therefore I can bet that random accesses wont occur. In this case would the 1st option be better than 2nd. Please help me figure out whether I am thinking in the right direction or not. Even if its a wild guess..please suggest. As your guess might help me in reaching my goal

Comment: I always assume that my DBMS is pretty smart when it comes to query optimization. There are lots of engineers working on that. Therefore, I assume that the DBMS does its best to reduce stuff like random access. The whole question of performance is highly dependent on how your data is stored and what hardware and software is it running on. In order to make a good decision, you should perform tests as Gordon suggested. E.g. the effects of random accesses are dependent on the storage you are accessing. My gut tells me option 2 is better as you are cutting out the join as an influencing factor.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to tell you but this schema just won't work for 'trillions' of records with any relational database. Just to store the index pages for serial_number and Designation for 1 trillion rows will require 465 terabytes. That is more than double the size of the entire World Data Centre for Climate database that currently holds the world record as the largest. If these requirements are for real, you really need to move to a star/snowflake schema. That means no varchars in this fact table, not even dates, only integers. Move all text and date fields to dimensions.

Comment: on a sidenote: the WDCC database surpassed the 465TB mark last year, see [here](http://www.dkrz.de/daten-en/wdcc/statistics/wdcc-statistics-2012) :-)

Comment: Sure if I store the fact table as integers by using a dictionary. Then which one of the 2 options would you suggest

Comment: @#VladG. . . . I have personally worked on databases that store 8 Petabytes.  Do be careful though that "trillion" can mean different things in different English-speaking countries.  In the US, it means 1,000 billion (which is 1,000 million (which is 1,000 one thousand)).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: You mean that in the USA "trillion" means 1E12 ( ~ 1T) , I thought that what it is in GB, too?

Comment: @wildplasser . . . Check out the Wikipedia reference (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers).  My understanding (which could be an American bias) is that the short form (prevalent in the US) is the form used for values in computer science.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: sorry, I am too old to remember that. I prefer the 1E12 notation, since it avoids ambiguity. Never liked BTU and Fahrenheit, either ;-)

Comment: @Rose -- a few questions: 1) what are your DBMS options? 2) how many distinct designations are there (an estimate) 3) how many unique names? 4) What is the nature of the timeOfJoining and timeOfLeaving, is this some type of time tracking system, or is it joining and leaving a company? 5) are you just querying places or also names? 6) the query as you wrote it may return billions of records. It will never be fast as written. Are you really interested in all managers who joined or left within a 20 year time period?

Answer (score 0):

For the most part a single table makes some sense, but it would be ridiculous to store all those values as strings, depending on the uniqueness of your name/designation/place fields you could use something like this:

```
 serial_number         | BIGINT  
 name_ID               | INT   
 Designation_ID        | INT 
 place_ID              | INT    
 timeOfJoining         | timestamp with time zone 
 timeOfLeaving         | timestamp with time zone
```

Without knowing the data it's impossible to know which lookups would be practical. As others have mentioned you've got some challenges ahead. Regarding indexing, I agree with Gordon.

Comment: Dont you think that even with date indexes, random accesses need to be made to the disk to find out the entire row. Therefore if I use the first option and store lexicographically by designation, then name and place. Then dont you think so that it will be faster. Please help me figure out whether I am thinking in the right direction or not. Please

Comment: With option 1 you at some point have to make a hideous JOIN between two huge tables, right? Wouldn't you have just as many records in each table via option 1?  That massive redundancy on a table of significant size is crippling.  You want every field in your query to be indexed as Gordon mentions.

Comment: Actually I have a lot of null values for timeOfJoining and timeOfLeaving. Also I dont think..there is a lot of redundancy..its just that the serial no. is getting redundantly stored. And since serial no. is an integer. Would it make much difference. Please suggest

Comment: No redundancy? My guesses of the cardinality ("entropy") of the dimensions: serial_number := 0 bits? (redundant surrogate key) name := 20 bits, designation := 8 bits, place := 8 bits, timestamps <= 32 bits.  {designation,place} could possibly violate BCNF, too, which could gain you some bits.

Comment: There just doesn't seem to be any benefit to the first option as you describe it.  The index covering fields starting with designation won't perform better if the timestamps are removed from the table.